# Calculate Future Date in MS Word

Tags: vba, date, ms-word

I am trying to calculate a future date with MS-Word Form Fields.  I pulled this code from http://word.tips.net/T001476_Calculating_a_Future_Date.html, and tried to make it work for me.  It throws an error stating "Object required".  The code is within a macro, and the macro is called when the frmApprovalDate field is exited.

```
Dim approvalDate As Date
approvalDate = frmApprovalDate.Text
frmExpirationDate.Text = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, approvalDate)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error in? Do you have a control called `frmExpirationDate`?

Comment: `frmExpirationDate` is a form field in the document.  The error is given on `approvalDate = frmApprovalDate.Text`.  It does not seem to recognize `frmApprovalDate` when I am debugging it.

Comment: Try `frmApprovalDate.Range.Text`

Comment: May I see your word document?

Comment: If you tell me how to post it.

Comment: Can upload it in www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/448032/testing.docx. Password to unprotect it is tgfbeta.

Comment: Refresh you page. You see see an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim approvalDate As Date

approvalDate = ActiveDocument.FormFields("frmApprovalDate").Range.Text

ActiveDocument.FormFields("frmExpirationDate").Result = _
DateAdd("yyyy", 1, approvalDate)
```